# How to plot serial signal from a sensor in a python dash app?

Tags: python, serialization, pyserial, plotly-dash

I am trying to read the analog input from an arduino uno and continuously display new input in a dash GUI. Reading the USB serial signal from the arduino is pretty much straigthforward with the pyserial package.

However, I could not yet implement a readout within Dash.

What I got so far is this code where an intervall event is triggered every 1000 ms and the generated data is added to a plot (updated):

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import os
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import serial
import time, datetime


os.system("start \"\" http://127.0.0.1:8050/") # necessary since dash does not automatically open browser

# readout function for analog signal reading
def readAO():
    ser = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=9600, timeout=10)
    dat = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
    ser.close()
    return dat

# arrays for saving data points
X = [0]
Y = [0]

# GUI layout/design
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1('Datenauswertung '),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-graph'),
        dcc.Interval(id='update_graph', interval=1000),
        html.Button(id='textout', children='text')
    ]
)

# update part where data is read and the plot and data arrays are updated
@app.callback(Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
              [Input('update_graph', 'n_intervals')])
def update(i_input):
    
    # this is where the Error happens
    dat = readAO()

    if(dat > 100 | dat < 600):
        Y.append(float(1))
        X.append(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    
    if len(X) > 50:
        del(X[0])
        del(Y[0])
    
    plot = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=X, y=Y, mode='markers+lines'))
    return plot     
     
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

And what I get is this error:

`serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied', None, 5)`

Which I don't understand. I am the only user of the PC, so admin permission is given. The following also performs just fine:

```
while(True):
    ser = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=9600, timeout=10)
    dat = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
    print(dat)
    ser.close()
```

One thing that irritates me, when I execute the code within the while loop I sometimes get faulty results (without an error).

Might this be a problem with the configuration of the serial connection, i.e. mismatch of timeout settings or similar?

Thanks everyone for your help and insights !

edit:
okay I localised the problem further. It seems readline() goes in to an error every now and then, so encapsulating the serial read in a try except catches this. It definitely also seems that Dash and pyserial don't work together very well. What I am stuck with is that readline() constantly outputs the same value more or less

Comment: I just ran into the same issue. Dash and PySerial appear to be incompatible. I not sure why  and would to also like to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since I am unfamiliar with Dash specifically, it's tough to diagnose exactly what is going wrong here. However, my other experiences with Python and Arduinos suggests some troubleshooting suggestions, in the order I'd suggest trying them:

1. Try unplugging and plugging your Arduino, and close other programs that might be trying to use the COM port. Typically (always?) only one program can open a given COM port at a time. The second program will get a permission denied error.
2. Try initializing the Serial port outside of the callback function. I.e., open the com port in early in the script, leaving its "ser" object as a global variable.
3. Maybe the Dash windows aren't automatically given admin permissions. Try explicitly running your Python prompt as an administrator. (By right-clicking the app icon when you're trying to open the command line, terminal, Python IDE, or whatever you're using.)

You're correct in guessing that BAUD rate or timeout settings could be an issue in general, but the serial initialization lines in both of your sample codes were identical, so I doubt that's the issue here.

Comment: To add more information, I have found I can start a Serial connection and use it, but the second I start up the Dash server it raises an `PermissionError` on the Serial connection. Is it possible that the Dash app startup block some sort of access?